# During my SKProductRequest my UIButtons and UILabels become nil. (XCODE 7)

Tags: xcode, null, uibutton

First time using XCODE and Objective C. Having an issue with my UIButtons and UILabels becoming nil during my SKProductRequest method.

Below is my ShopViewController.m, where initially call my 3 UIButtons and my UILabel. In the viewDidLoad my UIButtons and Label have content.

My Shop page loads correctly but once the ProductsRequest method is called the UIButtons and UILabels become nil, not sure why. All the items are (strong, nonatomic) properties in the .h file and have been linked to the referencing Outlets in the ShopViewController. Any help is really appreciated.

ShopViewController.m below the product request is made with the GetProductInfo method. Which is called from my *homeViewController when I press the buy button on the main game viewController.

```
#import "ShopViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ShopViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *homeViewController;

@end

@implementation ShopViewController
@synthesize fvProductTitle;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
_fvBuyButton.enabled = YES;
_ddBuyButton.enabled = NO;
_bundleBuyButton.enabled = NO;

fvProductTitle.text = @"don't read this";
}

- (IBAction)buyFVProduct:(id)sender {
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:_fvProduct];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

- (IBAction)buyDDProduct:(id)sender {
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:_ddProduct];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

- (IBAction)buyBundleProduct:(id)sender {
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:_bundleProduct];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

- (void) getProductInfo:(ViewController *) viewController {
_homeViewController = viewController;

if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
{
    SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                                  initWithProductIdentifiers:
                                  [NSSet setWithObjects:self.bundleProductID, self.ddProductID, self.fvProductID, nil]];
    request.delegate = self;

    [request start];
}
else{
    _fvProductDescription.text = @"please enable app purchases";
}
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
NSArray *products = response.products;

if (products.count != 0)
{
    _fvProduct = products[2];
    _fvBuyButton.enabled = YES;
    fvProductTitle.text = _fvProduct.localizedTitle;

    _ddProduct = products[1];
    _ddBuyButton.enabled = YES;
    _ddProductTitle.text = _ddProduct.localizedTitle;

    _bundleProduct = products[0];
    _bundleBuyButton.enabled = YES;
    _bundleProductTitle.text = _bundleProduct.localizedTitle;

} else {
    fvProductTitle.text = @"Full Version Product not found";
    _ddProductTitle.text = @"Dirty Dozen Product not found";
    _bundleProductTitle.text = @"Bundle Product not found";
}

products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionObserver

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
{
    switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            [self unlockFullVersion];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
             finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
             finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Here is my ShopViewController.h to see properties I have set up.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface ShopViewController : UIViewController   <SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate> {

}

@property (nonatomic) BOOL *isFullVersionAvailable;

// Store Kit
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKProduct *fvProduct;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKProduct *ddProduct;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKProduct *bundleProduct;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *fvProductID;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *ddProductID;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *bundleProductID;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *fvBuyButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *ddBuyButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *bundleBuyButton;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fvProductTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ddProductTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bundleProductTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *fvProductDescription;

- (IBAction)buyFVProduct:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)buyDDProduct:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)buyBundleProduct:(id)sender;
- (void)getProductInfo:(UIViewController *)viewController;

@end
```

My ViewController.m below, my purchaseItem is what the user presses to transition to the shop page and calls the getProductInfo method.

```
- (IBAction)purchaseItem:(id)sender {
shopViewController.fvProductID = @"BurnsyBadges.FullVersion";
shopViewController.ddProductID = @"BurnsyBadges.DirtyDozen";
shopViewController.bundleProductID = @"BurnsyBadges.Bundle";

[shopViewController getProductInfo: self];
}
```

Comment: You've left out much of the important details. Where is the product request made? Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: I've added more code of my entire ShopViewController.m and the IBAction that the user presses from the *homeViewController (the main game state).

Comment: I believe problem is here: _homeViewController = viewController;

Comment: @AlexKosyakov nothing seems wrong there, the _homeViewController contains the same info as when it came from the original game page.

Answer (score 0):

To Answer my own question. I had figured it out a few weeks ago and didn't get to update this. But it was a few things I had to correct in order to get multiple ViewControllers to access the Product Purchase Page correctly.

To get the one page working I needed to add a NavigationController to all my ViewControllers.